# Rails cookies.signed[:value] use what cryptographic algorithms to encrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, encryption, railstutorial.org

I know cookie.signed is signed by rails app's `secrets.secret_key_base` value. I think it must be a symmetric-key algorithm. How can I know what cryptographic algorithm that use ?

Answer (score 2):

AES is being used to encrypt and sign session data. See [here](http://big-elephants.com/2014-01/handling-rails-4-sessions-with-go/)